# Postgresql replica: compare tables in publisher and subscriptor

Tags: postgresql, function, replication, procedure, ddl

I've got Postgresql 11 server and logical replica.
Our teammates from command which is publisher like to rename or add columns
in tables, which we recieve as subscriptor. Sometimes replica falls,
because of this changes.
I want to write a procedure or function which will be a part of Jenkins job.
If they change columns and they are different from DDL of subscriptor, then
there will be something like error.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You could turn on audit logging for DDL using pgaudit, setting pgaudit.log to 'DDL' and then detect log entries. https://github.com/pgaudit/pgaudit/blob/master/README.md#pgauditlog

Comment: Can't install addition functionality on database:( But your idea is nice
I thought maybe somehow compare pg_dumps of two schemas or tables.